# CQ Basic Authentication

Tags: aem

i have a requirement to implement basic authentication  at dispatcher side

I have below basic auth configuration in my virtual host(www.abc.com) configuration file.

```
<Location /content/abc/jp-JP >
  AuthType basic
  AuthName "private area"
  AuthBasicProvider file
  AuthUserFile /opt/cq/www/htdocs/password(this is name of file, contains uname and password)
  Require valid-user 
</Location>
```

when i try to access www.abc.com/jp-JP getting basic auth prompt and authenticated succefully from password file(username and password file ) located under  /opt/cq/www/htdocs . after first prompt successfully validated username and password , second prompt displaying with requires username and password .The server Says (Sling development). if i disable basic authentication in apache sling authentication service of publish instance ..then it's redirecting me to correct page what i expected ..but unable to publish contents from author(blocked inside replication agent queue). so enabled back..but basic authentication blocked with The server Says (Sling development).

I am sure it is difficult to understand what i am trying to say here ..but any idea how to by pass prompt of  "The server Says (Sling development)" from dispatcher level basic auth. Any help would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me paraphrase your description: you have setup HTTP Basic Auth on the Apache level and it works fine, but the credentials entered in the browser are sent not only to the Apache but also to the CQ. CQ treats credentials as its own username and password and returns error. Disabling *HTTP Basic Authentication Handler* authenticator is not an option, as it's used by the replication process.

In order to make Apache HTTP Basic and the CQ publish coexists, you can remove the `Authorization` header (used in the HTTP Basic Auth) on the Apache, using [`mod_headers` module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html) and its `RequestHeader` directive. Enable the `mod_headers` and place following line in your VirtualHost configuration:

```
RequestHeader unset Authorization
```

Apache will use the header to authenticate the request, but then it'll be removed and CQ won't get it.

Comment: Thank you very much.. This solved my problem.. Very useful information